# how to set env variable for yarn installed package?

Tags: kali-linux, environment-variables, node.js

I installed babel-cli package via yarn globally

```
yarn add babel-cli global
```

I need to set env variable.documentation says bin folder should be here

```
~/.config/yarn/global.
```

inside there are 4 js files. here is the path but i could not set it.

```
~/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/babel-cli/bin$
```

i did try all combinations: instead of ~, i placed home, i omitted last $ sign, i omitted . from .config. I could not figure out.

Comment: Kali Linux is a WYSIWYG operating system. Installing anything is not really supported. Can you install your compiler on a different operating system and use that to develop on?